# Deserializing list of different objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Let's say, I have the the following C# classes

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Parent
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int SharedProp { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : Parent
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ChildAProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB : Parent
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ChildAProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now I created a `List<Parent>` to which holds zero to n objects. Serialization of the list works fine and gives me a valid JSON file which I can deserialize. The problem is, I am currently only getting `List<Parent>` back and there is no `ChildA` or `ChildB` object.

I am using the [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) serializer/deserializer. Is there any way to achieve this or do I have to split it into separate files/lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `TypeNameHandling` in the `JsonSerializerSettings`. Take a look at [this article](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) for an example.

Comment: Works perfectly! Important is, that I also have to use this in the deserialization process.